# Execute .sh script on ec2 instances without rebooting

Tags: amazon-web-services, ec2-ami

I currently keep my app code on S3 and have a startup.sh script which is fired via /etc/rc.local and installs the apps and any edits etc. Thus when I make a change, I need to reboot all my instances for the change to take effect.

Is there a way to trigger the script without rebooting the instance?

EDIT:

I do not want to individually log into all my instances. I would prefer a method that I can script up to apply to all my instances at once - which are in an autoscaling group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use tools like Chef and Puppet to achieve this.

Thats the recommended way (at least whenever there are Amazon Linux AMIs), and actually, as looking by your needs, seems to be the case. Its actually [even supported for Amazon CloudFormation](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/IntegratingAWSCloudFormationWithPuppet.pdf), I think.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just login to the instance and run the script? See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8919031/667608) on how to setup a server and login.

Based on your edit, you have 3 options IMO.

1. Use CSSHX - awesome program
2. Do it manually - as you said, this is a pain.
3. Use chef or puppet or RightScale