# I cannot acess to the website host on Amazon EC2 instance even I think the configuration is right

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have a free Amazon EC2 instance. And I installed Apache web server on it. I have the DNS record for my domain point to the ip for the EC2 instance. I can not access to my website. Then I looked up and allow the http inbound. But I still failed to access my web? What might be the reason. Anybody gives me a clue?

Answer (score 13):

Go to the AWS management console and look at the Security Group the instance is in. Then make sure you have the port open that you are trying to connect to (most likely 80). To open it to the world set the ip range to 0.0.0.0/0 and to open it to a specific ip (like only your house) set it to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32.

That is almost always the reason people have problems connecting when they are new to AWS. I wrote [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8919031/667608), which should help get you setup.

Comment: From my relatively brief experience with AWS, I can say the weakest part of their system is not alerting users to potential pitfalls like this. 
AWS Marketplace Usage Instructions
Latest Versions: 1.3
Once your AMI is running, enter the Public DNS into your web browser to access the Wordpress interface. (SHOULD SAY CHECK SECURITY GROUP SETTINGS IF ISSUES ENCOUNTERED CONNECTING TO SERVER)